# have composer update get latest version from git repo

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I am trying to move away from git submodules for the development in my team. The most important reason for this is that when a team member commits changes in a submodule, but forgets to push to origin, but does push the reference to this new commit in the "root" project, origin is broken, and the other developers get the `reference is not a tree` error. This can be problematic if the developer in question pushed before going home, and that reference that is not a tree points to a commit on the developers laptop, which is in his bag, in a train somewhere.

I am trying to replace git submodules with composer. My reasoning is that if git doesn't know about my dependencies, these dependencies can't break the repo. I know how to add packages from packagist, and I also managed to add our own git repositories to composer, mainly with the help from [this blog post](http://www.craftitonline.com/2012/03/how-to-use-composer-without-packagist-like-a-newbie/).

The problem, and the last piece of the puzzle, is that our dependencies are git repositories that we are actively working on. If I push an update to one of our dependencies, I would like the local copies of the developers to update to this latest version when they do a `composer update`. The closest I got is to create a tag for each change to a dependency, and then update my composer.json with the id of this new tag.

What I would like to know, is if there is a way to have composer always check out the latest commit of a certain branch, or, if this is not possible, to always get the latest tag when I do a `composer update`. I don't really mind the tagging, I just don't want to keep updating composer.json during development.

The composer file I have for testing:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "app/vendor"
    },
    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "wkjagt/seagull",
                "version": "1.0",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@github.com:wkjagt/Seagull.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "wkjagt/seagull": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

I was expecting the `1.0.*` to take the latest tag starting with 1.0, but once composer already has 1.0.1, it won't get 1.0.2 if I create it. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you won't have to specify each version separately in your repositories section, you'll need to add a `composer.json` file to **wkjagt/Seagull** and include the package like this:

```
{
   "type": "vcs",
   "url": "https://github.com/wkjagt/Seagull"
},
```

Composer can then read through your tags and treat them as versions. If you always want the get the latest version require your package with the dev flag:

```
"require": {
    "wkjagt/seagull": "@dev"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out. As an added bonus, my main composer file is a lot smaller now.

Comment: Also have a look at http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Comment: Thank you, very interesting, and worth a look. But I would like to avoid hosting an additional project if I don't really need to.

Comment: I don't know why, but I think the "@dev" made it work. Thanks!

Comment: @inakiabt That's because per default composer has a [minimum-stability](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) setting 'stable' and therefore it does not 'see' the dev versions, unless you specify it in your **root** `composer.json`. Either per package or for the whole project.