# Composer pulling latest commits on separate repos

Tags: git, composer-php

I am using separate on-line repositories for my Wordpress theme (built on [roots](http://roots.io)) and for my themes plugins. **Each of my plugins use a separate on-line repository.** The roots theme comes with a `composer.json` for easy deploys.

My plugins are in a separate directory to the theme and its corresponding `composer.json`

```
/web/app/plugins/respective_plugin
```

I do not use `--tags` when pushing commits on my plugins. I want to configure Composer to download the latest `dev` commits (and an option for latest `master`) of these separate repositories in their separate directories regardless of `--tags` or not.

I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916183/how-do-i-get-composer-to-download-the-latest-commit-in-the-master-branch-from-gi) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595772/have-composer-update-get-latest-version-from-git-repo) threads which may be pointing me in the right direction, but I cannot work out how to set them up correctly.

**EDIT:**

Can someone give an example of a `composer.json` pulling the latest dev commits from multiple online repos into separate directories please? I have read the documentation but it is not newbie friendly. I have dumped my entire `composer.json` for sake of ease.

```
{
  "name": "roots/bedrock",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "A modern WordPress stack",
  "homepage": "http://roots.io/wordpress-stack/",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Scott Walkinshaw",
      "email": "scott.walkinshaw@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/swalkinshaw"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben Word",
      "email": "ben@benword.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/retlehs"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "wordpress", "stack", "capistrano", "composer", "vagrant", "wp"
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues",
    "forum": "http://discourse.roots.io/category/bedrock"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "generate-salts": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Roots\\Bedrock\\Installer": "scripts"}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": ["Roots\\Bedrock\\Installer::addSalts"]
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "http://wpackagist.org"
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "wordpress/wordpress",
        "version": "4.0.1",
        "type": "webroot",
        "dist": {
          "type": "zip",
          "url": "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.0.1.zip"
        },
        "require" : {
          "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.1.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "wordpress/wordpress": "4.0.1",
    "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.1.0",
    "composer/installers": "v1.0.12",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0.6",
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/app/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
      "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "web/app/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "webroot-dir": "web/wp",
    "webroot-package": "wordpress/wordpress"
  }
}
```

Comment: The ~1.0.6 will update to any version in the 1.0 tagged versions. I think of it as anything up to and including 1.0.9999999....  ~1.0 would potentially update 1.99999(etc) if it was tagged as such.

Answer (score 2):

Composer will do just that every time you run `composer update`. It will look at the most current commit of the package that you have to include like this: `"require": { "your/templatepackage":"dev-development"}` (note that the branch name is "development", and the "dev-" prefix is put there by Composer).

Composer will not automatically update, because that would contradict it's purpose: Install RELIABLE versions that at some point were considered working. If you don't like updating everything, you could restrict the packages to update like this: `composer update your/templatepackage`. This will only install the latest commit of this package - if it is allowed by your other version dependencies. The latest commit might not be installed if it depends itself on a version of another package that is newer than the installed version of this package, and deemed incompatible, e.g. the newest commit depends on `~1.2`, but the installed version is 1.1.25, which is incompatible with the minimum requirement of 1.2.0.

Comment: Additionally adding the `"minimum-stability": "dev"` setting with the required version set to `"*"` should get the latest commit regardless of branch when you update.